# Learning how to make tables for data

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, html-table

I'm making a table that takes in a phone number, subscribed boolean and groups. My current table does not have the incoming date fall in line like it should. I believe this is a simple html problem but for whatever reason I can't come up with the solution. Here is some code and a screenshot of what I'm working with.

```
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <% @people.each do |person| %>
        <th><%= person.phone_number %></th>
      <% end %>
      <% @people.each do |person| %>
        <th><%= person.subscribed %></th>
      <% end %>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
```

[image]

As you can see it's not listing but just inlining across the screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
<tbody>
 <% @people.each do |person| %>
     <tr>

        <th><%= person.phone_number %></th>


        <th><%= person.subscribed %></th>
        <th><%= person.group %></th>

    </tr>
 <% end %>
</tbody>
```

Comment: That almost gets it but it still does not list? it's still inline.

Comment: Yes you missed the group column